# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: On InitializeComponent caused by own control

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have problems creating own control: I'm trying to make grid view similar to list view. The problem is in xaml file of the page - when I'm initializing my component app crashes on that page with file not found exception.

> **Error says**:  System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly 'FastFood' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> **Callstack**:
>
> ```
>     _at System.AppDomain.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity)
> ```
>
> [0x00081] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:706
>
> ```
> at System.AppDomain.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef) [0x00000] in
> ```
>
> /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:674
>
> ```
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef) [0x00000] in
> ```
>
> /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:551
>
> ```
> at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.GetElementType (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlType xmlType, IXmlLineInfo xmlInfo,
> ```
>
> System.Reflection.Assembly currentAssembly,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException& exception) [0x00133] in :0 
>       at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.CreateValuesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, INode parentNode) [0x0002a] in
>   :0
>       at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode) [0x000b1] in :0 
>       at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode) [0x00089] in :0 
>       at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept (IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode) [0x00064] in :0 
>       at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject view, System.String xaml) [0x000a4] in
>   :0 
>       at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject view, System.Type callingType) [0x0002e]
>   in :0 
>       at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[CategoryPage] (FastFood.CategoryPage view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in :0 
>       at FastFood.CategoryPage.InitializeComponent () [0x0000c] in /Users/Slider/Coffetab/iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/FastFood.iOS..Users.Slider.Coffetab.FastFood.CategoryPage.xaml.g.cs:33
>
> ```
> at FastFood.CategoryPage..ctor () [0x0001a] in /Users/Slider/Coffetab/FastFood/CategoryPage.xaml.cs:25 
> at FastFood.MenuPage..ctor () [0x0004b] in /Users/Slider/Coffetab/FastFood/MenuPage.xaml.cs:14 
> at FastFood.MainPage.OnLogin (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0002f] in
> ```
>
> /Users/Slider/Coffetab/FastFood/MainPage.xaml.cs:29 
>       at Xamarin.Forms.Button.Xamarin.Forms.IButtonController.SendClicked ()
>   [0x00020] in :0 
>       at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer.OnButtonTouchUpInside (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) [0x0000e] in :0 
>       at UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs:37
>
> ```
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
> at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in
> ```
>
> /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:77
>
> ```
> at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in
> ```
>
> /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:61
>
> ```
> at FastFood.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0001a] in /Users/Slider/Coffetab/iOS/Main.cs:23_
> ```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Years later (for you) but I found a solution on a forum.

> I've encountered this some other times with other components and NuGet
>   packages. You'll probably have to live with the fact that you have to
>   include a dummy line of code which instantiates the ExtendedSlider. It
>   doesn't have to do anything, just reference it somewhere.
>
> When you're using it in just XAML the compiler doesn't detect the
>   reference and thus excludes the needed dll. Until the creator of the
>   component finds some fix for this you'll have to use this workaround.

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/187222/#Comment_187222

So just add a random `var foo = new YourComponentFromTheAssemblyInQuestion();` anywhere in your code and it shouldn't complain anymore.

Maybe this will help others stumbling upon the same issue later on like I did.